# nine patch line is being shown

Tags: android, textview, nine-patch

The nine patch line are being shown when I'm running it on the actual device. Previewing the xml file on eclipse works just fine, no black line on top and bottom of my image. However running in on actual device, the line is being shown.

I've already tried editing it in drawninepatch.  The filename includes .9, and I've already tried setting the padding to 0dp. BTW, I'm setting the background of a TextView here.

Sorry, here goes:

[image]

Comment: Add the image. We cannot guess your mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you draw only top line. No left line.

for nine patch top and left lines are must. If you do not want to scale `left` line then just make it complete. You can not leave it empty.

Right and bottom are optional. But if you seting content padding for `Right`, then to draw line for bottom is must!

Answer (score 0):

This image contains top black line only. You should draw also left, right and bottom lines. Prefer using /android-sdk-linux/tools/draw9patch

Comment: as far as i know, right and bottom lines are optional.  and I also didn't need to scale the left, i just need to the top to be scalable, that's why